# How to apply hover effect (increase font size) without affecting the overall inline text?

Tags: css

How to apply hover effect (increase font size) without affecting the overall inline text? I'm fairly new to css. Your help will be appreciate!

*line height is not working*

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML and CSS code?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :)

```css
.text{
font-size:20px; /* Font size you need in start*/
color:#333; /* font color #333 is hexadecimal code of black shade */
font-family:arial; /* font family to style the text */
font-weight:bold; /* To bold the text */
}
.text:hover{
transform:scale(1.5); /* The deafult value is 1 if you change it to any value less than one it will be smaal and vise versa large */}


 /* YOU CAN ADD ANIMATION TOO FOR SMOOTH RESIZE */
.smooth{transition:all 0.3s;}
```

```html
<center> <!-- The center tag is used to align the text in center -->
<p class="text"> PIXALVOOP - TEXT RESIZE</p>
<p class="text smooth"> PIXALVOOP - SMOOTH </p>
<center> <!-- The center tag is used to align the text in center -->
```